# How to loop an animation or digital ad

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am doing this digital ad and wanting to make it play more then 3 times, not sure on what code to write to make it go infinite time.

Right now the code is set up for playing 3 times then stopping.

Comment: Please show some code that you have tried.

Comment: Edit your question to include your current code.  If not really apparent, explain what things in your code are.  Then someone can actually help

Comment: What code is making it play times only? That might be a good place to start.

Comment: The code i used is 
if (!loopCount) {
  var loopCount:Number = 0;
}
loopCount++;
if (loopCount >= i) {
  this.stop();
}

Answer (score 0):

Frame One:

```
if(!repeatCounter){
    var repeatCounter:int=0;
}
if(repeatCounter<desiredAnimationRepetition){
    play();
}else{
    stop();
}
```

Final Frame:

```
repeatCounter++;
gotoAndPlay(1);
```

And that's all there is to it.